# How many minutes of Lunar Sim did Neil Armstrong get?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, apollo-program, nasa, training, lltv

A quick follow-up to [What were the differences between the LLRV and LLTV?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/what-were-the-differences-between-the-llrv-and-lltv)

These craft were provided with a [zero-zero ejection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ejection_seat#Zero-zero_ejection_seat) seat. The above referenced article on Wikipedia mentions Neil Armstrong apparently had to exercise that option back in 1968 too. *I vaguely recall mention that a pilot experiencing that kind of acceleration, and relatively hard landing is usually not put back in the cock-pit in a hurry*; I could be wrong though ...

- How many minutes of [Lunar Sim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Landing_Research_Vehicle#Lunar_Sim_Mode) did Neil Armstrong get in total before, and after his ejection?

  - In comparison, did the other crews get significantly more time in these vehicles?
- What was the policy on graduating the back-up crew if the planned crew had to eject from these contraptions?

Comment: Neil actually made the 8 flights between Jun 14 and 17, 1969, so he had a month to spare. Management clearance was given Jun 3, not 30, to resume training in the LLTV.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, we can make some rough approximation based on the information in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Landing_Research_Vehicle#Lunar_Landing_Training_Vehicle.5B5.5D):

> The test program of 18 flights, all flown by Bud Ream, was successfully completed on June 2, and the Board finally gave approval on June 30, 1969 for Neil Armstrong to resume LLTV flights. In the 16 days remaining before the Apollo 11 launch Armstrong was able to complete his LLTV flight training. He commented after his return:
>
> “Eagle (the Lunar Module) flew very much like the Lunar Landing Training Vehicle which I had flown **more than 30 times** at Ellington Air Force Base near the Space Center. I had made from 50 to 60 landings in the trainer, and the final trajectory I flew to the landing was very much like those flown in practice. That of course gave me a good deal of confidence – a comfortable familiarity.”

Wikipedia also says that the LLRV had an "endurance" of 10 minutes. Assuming that this means a single flight could take up 10 minutes, and that the same number holds for the LLTV as well, this gives about 300 minutes.